# Could not open filter-no-eval.js in the editor

Tags: reactjs, windows, whitelist

I need using the groupable feature in react kendo like that example https://stackblitz.com/run/?file=app%2Fmain.jsx

but I have this error in vscode:

> Could not open filter-no-eval.js in the editor. When running on
>   Windows, file names are checked against a whitelist to protect against
>   remote code execution attacks. File names may ttacks. File names may
>   consist only of alphanumeric characters (all languages), periods,
>   dashes, slashes, and underscores.

any suggestion?